# How can I access an array item's sibling in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, siblings

So I have an array that I dynamically generate and looks like this:

```
$array[1] = array(
    'item1' => 'value1',
    'item2' => 'value2',
    'item3' => 'value3',
    'item4' => 'value4',
    'item5' => 'value5'
);

$array[2] = array(
    'item1' => 'value100',
    'item2' => 'value200',
    'item3' => 'value300',
    'item4' => 'value400',
    'item5' => 'value500'
);

...
```

Now I have the value of 'item2' = 'value2'coming from somewhere else

I'm trying to find a way, with only one line of code,  to access all the items in the array where 'item2' = 'value2' and modify the value of 'item4'

I could easily do something like this if I knew that I needed to change it for array[1] only:

```
$array[1]['item4'] = 'new value';
```

But I need to update the value only for the items where 'item2' is equal to 'value2'

I know I could loop thought it but I'm trying to find a way to do it with only one line of code. jQuery can easily find siblings when they match a certain criteria maybe there is something similar in PHP I'm not aware of?

Comment: may I ask why only one line of code?

Comment: What do you mean by, "with only one line of code"?

Comment: I have this array in a session and I want to be able to update it in this fashion: $array[$key]['item4'] = 'new value'; (where item2 = value2)

Comment: you could write a whole framework in one line of code. the question is how long the line will be ;)

Comment: Looks like it wasn't only me who was confused by "one line of code".  You can put multiple semicolons in one line of code and make it a mile long. :)  Maybe he means one "expression" not sure if that also makes sense. Not sure why some prefer writing smaller variables, smaller function names and fewer lines.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps

```
$array[1] = array(
    'item1' => 'value1',
    'item2' => 'value2',
    'item3' => 'value3',
    'item4' => 'value4',
    'item5' => 'value5'
);

$array[2] = array(
    'item1' => 'value100',
    'item2' => 'value200',
    'item3' => 'value300',
    'item4' => 'value400',
    'item5' => 'value500'
);

function test(&$item, $key){
    if($item['item2'] == 'value2'){
        $item['item4'] = 'new value';
    }
}

array_walk($array, 'test');
```

Answer (score 2):

its not very pretty but here:

```
foreach($array as &$child) { if($child['item2'] == 'value2') { $child['item4'] = 'new value'; }}
```

I hope no one else needs to read your code...